# How can i do animate `marginLeft` using scroll trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have that js code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var h = $('#home').height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            ww = $(window).width(),
            s = $("#skills");

        scroll >= 0 && scroll < h + 299 ? s.addClass("first") : s.removeClass("first");
        scroll >= h + 299 && scroll < h + 599 ? s.addClass("second") : s.removeClass("second");
        scroll >= h + 600 && scroll < h + 899 ? s.addClass("third") : s.removeClass("third");
        scroll >= h + 900 && scroll < h + 1199 ? s.addClass("fourth") : s.removeClass("fourth");
        scroll >= h + 1200 && scroll < h + 1499 ? s.addClass("fifth") : s.removeClass("fifth");
        scroll >= h + 1500 && scroll < h + 1799 ? s.addClass("sixth") : s.removeClass("sixth");
        scroll >= h + 1800 && scroll < h + 2099 ? s.addClass("seventh") : s.removeClass("seventh");
        scroll >= h + 2100 && scroll < h + 2399 ? s.addClass("eighth") : s.removeClass("eighth");
        scroll >= h + 2400 ? s.addClass("ninth") : s.removeClass("ninth");

        scroll >= h && scroll <= h + 2699 ? $("a.about").addClass("active") : $("a.about").removeClass("active");

        scroll >= h + 2700 ? s.animate({ marginLeft: -ww }, 'slow') : s.animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 'slow');


    });

    $("a.about").click(function() { $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: h}, 'slow'); });

});
```

It's correctly does what I'm want. But, I can't successfully animate `marginLeft`. If start scroll from top of page, when you reach the condition for animate `scroll >= h + 2700` you need wait very much time, for animate is started. And if reload page just before `scroll >= h + 2700` and scroll down once, animate will do without delay.

What i need to do, for animate my block immediately when user reach `scroll >= h + 2700`?

And as far as the right to set the conditions as I set him for a count of checks to scroll? I mean so many almost identical rows.

**UPD**
I add `.stop()` animate is better now. But if you do not stop to scroll, animation animation is very much slower.

http://jsfiddle.net/ujmMk/5/ - I found it in Stack Overflow. You can understand what I'm saying if you will scroll that jsfiddle example.